# How to enable the keyboard shortcuts in WordPress?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, wordpress

I have admin access to our company blog but I am not able to use the keyboard shortcuts in WordPress. Is there any option to enable this? Also, where I can find the list of shortcuts for Mac?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about install-able software setup/configuration. This question could be on topic on [wordpress.se].

Comment: @Rubén: If this question is about wordpress.com or simply about _using_ the self-hosted version of WordPress, it's okay here. I don't know that there's enough information here for us to answer. Does WP even _have_ keyboard shortcuts? What browser is being used, for instance?

Comment: @AʟE. Thanks for your feedback. If it were possible I would change the closing reason to unclear what is being asked. Hopefully an expert on WP could help us to understand this question better.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use keyboard shortcuts in WordPress, you need to enable it on the admin panel. Please note that you need to do this for each user profile. Simply go to the user profile and check the keyboard shortcuts checkbox. 
You can download this [Google chrome extension](https://www.techwyse.com/wordpress-shortcuts/) to refer all the keyboard shortcuts in WordPress. If you're using Mac, replace the Ctrl key with Command key.